# Get selected option ID with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tabs with select option in each tab and I want it to be submitted in a specific URL assigned to them when I hit submit button. I'm doing this in javascipt. I'm really a newbie in javascript that's why I need your generous help.
I divided my select option according to their category using tabs, so my code is like this:
**HTML**

```
<ul class="ut-nav-tabs clearfix">
    <li class="active"><a href="#t1Tab" data-toggle="tab">Corporate Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
    <a href="#t2Tab" data-toggle="tab">Digital Marketing</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="t1Tab" class="tab-pane clearfix active">
    <form method="post" action="/trendstatic15/#wpcf7-f3409-o1">
        <select id="id_corporateservices">
            <option value="Can a foreign investors open his own company in the Philippines?">Can a foreign investors open his own company in the Philippines?</option>
            <option value="What are the business regulations currently used in the Philippines?">What are the business regulations currently used in the Philippines?</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

    <div id="t2Tab" class="">
        <form method="post" action="/trendstatic15/#wpcf7-f3409-o1">
            <select id="id_digitalservices">
            <option value="Should I add online video to my web sites?">Should I add online video to my web sites?</option>
            <option value="What works best in Internet marketing?">What works best in Internet marketing?">What works best in Internet marketing?">What works best in Internet marketing?</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function redirect() {
        var filename_corporate = document.getElementById('id_corporateservices').value;
        var filename_digital = document.getElementById('id_digitalservices').value;

        var url ='';

        if (filename_digital == 'What works best in Internet marketing?')
        {
            url= 'http://localhost/testsite/digital-page';
        }
        else if(filename_corporate == 'Can a foreign investors open his own company in the Philippines?')
        {
            url= 'http://localhost/testsite/corporate-page';
        }
        else
        {
         url= 'http://anyurlpage.com';
        }

        window.location = url;

        }
</script>
```

Why is that when I selected any in the option and then submitted it always direct to the first url condition http://localhost/testsite/digital-page?

Comment: `localhost` is the way your computer can reference your computer; it doesn't work from anywhere else.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed, meaning the opening tags do not have matching closing tags.  Please adjust your question for easier reading

Comment: vihan1086, I'm just giving an example url for this because right now I'm developing it in localhost

Comment: ochi, yes made changes again about the html, can you please review it again? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because you are always referring to the one element with id "id_digitalservices" that never changes? It does not matter if you change tabs visibility it still remains in DOM.

You can get the actually changed option value by using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function selectmenuOnchange(selectMenuId) {

    //Get the selectmenu element by Id
     var selectmenuID = document.getElementById(selectMenuId);
     //Get selected options value
     var optionValue = selectmenuID.options[selectmenuID.selectedIndex].value;

     //this should return the selectmenu's id
     alert(this.id);

     redirect(optionValue);

}

function redirect(optionValue) {

    var url ='';

    if (optionValue === 'What works best in Internet marketing?')
    {
        url= 'http://localhost/testsite/digital-page';
    }
    else if(optionValue === 'Can a foreign investors open his own company in the Philippines?')
    {
        url= 'http://localhost/testsite/corporate-page';
    }
    else
    {
     url= 'http://anyurlpage.com';
    }

    window.location = url;
}
</script>
```

You need to edit both of your selectmenus to include my onchange function like this:

HTML

```
<select onchange="selectmenuOnchange(this.id);">
```

Comment: Hi Defain, I really have no idea about DOM, what can I change on my code?

Comment: If I understand your intentions correctly the code in my answer should work. But you should never compare strings like you do there. Option values should be something else; integers for example.

Comment: the code you added still isn't working, it still directing to the first condition url

Comment: You need to do the same for the another select menu of course. And your code does accept the first if clause always when id_digitalservices selectmenu has the given value no matter what others have. If it has another value and id_corporateservices menu has the correct one it will be selected instead.

Comment: I revised it to this:
`var selectmenuID2 = document.getElementById('id_corporateservices').value;
        var filename_corporate = selectmenuID2.options[selectmenuID2.selectedIndex].value;

        var selectmenuID = document.getElementById("id_digitalservices");
        var filename_digital = selectmenuID.options[selectmenuID.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: sorry I'm trying hard to reformat my code comment to view it nicely like you did :)

Comment: I also tried your code revision using filename_corporateSelectmenuID.
But any select option I select is always going to the first URL condition

Comment: Hi Defain, I tried switching the `filename_corporateSelectmenuID` along with `filename_corporate` and put it at the bottom of the first Var which is `filename_digitalSelectmenuID`
Now I noticed that the last document.getElementById that has been set will be the code to always be follow when form is submitted

Comment: That is because you have two different selectmenus in DOM and the first one keeps it value even if you change the other one so it will redirect always to the first one. I edited my answer to trigger from changing the value of selectmenu. Please note that you need to update your HTML.

Comment: I added the `selectmenuOnchange` javascript function and added the `onchange="selectmenuOnchange();"`
and now the url goes to the last else condition which is the http://anyurlpage.com

Comment: Hi Defain, I noticed that the `optionValue` has no value because I did some `alert(optionValue);` and erased the `window.location = url` for the mean time.

The alert box shows but no printed value. Maybe that's why the last URL in the else condition is always giving the result.